# Steel plate thickness for load

Tags: steel, stresses

There is a steel plate with length of 26.5cm (10.4 inch)  and width of 4cm (1.57 inch). the steel plate is attached on one end, at the other end there is a load of 30kg, what thickness should be the plate so it will not bend ?

[image]

Comment: Could you provide any information on what you've tried so far? What part of the problem don't you understand/where are you getting stuck? Add this information to your question

Comment: Welcome to Engineering! This looks like a [homework question](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/q/121/1832). In order for such questions to be answered in this site, we need you to add details describing the precise problem you're having. What have you tried to solve this yourself? Please [edit] your question to include this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will always bend as steel has finite stiffness. You need to decide how much deflection is acceptable.

[This page](http://www.engineersedge.com/beam_calc_menu.shtml) lists the bending equations for a variety of loading situations. This case is a [cantilever with load at one end](http://www.engineersedge.com/beam_bending/beam_bending9.htm)

These equations do rely on some assumptions but should be fine for this situation, be aware though that they apply to static loads only, if the load moves the stresses involved can be significantly higher.

These equations also assume that stresses are within the elastic limit of the material, if the yield stress is exceeded then the beam will be permanently deformed and may fail completely.

As a rough guide I would say that you are looking at about 8mm thick or more

It is also worth nothing that a flat plate is a very inefficient way to support a cantilevered load and unless there is a strong reason why the support needs to be very slender you are much better off either adding an arch type support web below the beam or using a hollow section. For example a 25x25mm square tube with wall thickness of 2mm would support 30 kg no trouble with very small deflection at 27cm cantilever length and weigh much less than an equivalent 4cm wide strip.

you also need to consider the fact that there will be a large torsion load where the plate meets the thing it is attached to which is a common point of failure.